# How to rearrange 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I have a 3D array and I want to rearrange them so each position in each dimension still corresponds to the next dimension, but the order of all 3 are changed.

I have a 3D array:

`array = [32,30,96]`
The third dimension with 96 values I already ranked ordered to find that :

`ranks = [57 23 68 58 25 91 70 83 77 75 89 34 49 79 66 54 67 44 63 52 46 20 64 10 80 33 30 29 28 26 17 27 50 51 92 86 69 47  0  7  3 85 18 11 13 53  8 78 82 81 14 74 59 32 42 39  1 31 36 19 24  5 38  9 73 71 76 87 41 55 94 93 84 16 90 62 48 43 72 95 65 45 61 22 21 15 37 88  2 40 56  6 12 60  4 35]`

I want to rearrange the whole 3D array to reflect the rank order. SO I still want the same association across the array, but in a different order.

So i want a new array that has the same dimensions, newarray=[32,30,96] but where its order based off the last dimension so [32,30,ranks] i don't care about the specific value, position 0 doesn't have to become 57, I want all the data corresponding to position 57 to now be position 0